# DOM Element Flickers when appending to another element. Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

http://premier-research.headspacedesign.ca/

In the featured experts section, when I click on the prev and next buttons the Features Expert title and action buttons flicker. When the buttons are clicked I am appending div to another element absolutely position below the featured experts text. This only happens in Safari for some reason...

Can you please offer some direction?

Comment: It doesn't happen with Safari on my laptop - Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17).

Comment: I applied and overflow-x: hidden to the containing div and it stops flickering...